# macOS: Programmatically access the "Screen On Usage" data shown in Settings->Battery

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, power-management, pmset

[image]

How do I programmatically access the "Screen On Usage" data shown in Settings->Battery?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @nohillside I can find the last time AC was connected using `pmset -g log | rg --ignore-case 'using AC\b' `.

Comment: Do you want to automatically open the Settings pane, or do you want to access the data shown there?

Comment: @nohillside I want to access the data.